# AWS S3: generating a pre-signed URL

Tags: namedcredentials, amazon-s3

I am trying to generate an AWS S3 pre-signed from Salesforce apex to use later to download file in lwc, see following sample code:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('GET');

// Set the URL to the named credential endpoint
request.setEndpoint('callout:myamazon/generatePresignedUrl/&bucketName=sfspfiles?objectKey=sfspfiles/21032024150342_5006u0000071zTXAAY_FAQs.png');

// Set request parameters
request.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
// Send the request
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(request);

System.debug(res.getBody());
System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
System.debug(res.getStatus());
```

it gives me error 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'

used named credential is working file - tested using upload file 'PUT'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 - Specifying SSE-S3 with pre-signed URL's usingAPEX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/amazon-s3-specifying-sse-s3-with-pre-signed-urls-usingapex)

Comment: You won't be able to use AWS Sig V4 support in Named Cred for this task. Either adapt the Apex code from the referenced answer or [move the generation to client side](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript)

Comment: thanks, i trying to use named credential and on servver side to secure access and security key.

Comment: if i use 'request.setEndpoint('callout:myamazon');' then it works fine and return list of buckets. Issue is with request.setEndpoint('callout:myamazon/generatePresignedUrl&bucketName=sfspfiles?objectKey=sfspfiles/21032024150342_5006u0000071zTXAAY_FAQs.png');

Comment: `generatePresignedUrl&bucketName=sfspfiles` would be incorrect. `?` starts the query string, so: `callout:myamazon/generatePresignedUrl?bucketName=sfspfiles&objectKey=sfspfiles/21032024150342_5006u0000071zTXAAY_FAQs.png`

Comment: thanks for response, It gives different error: <Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>generatePresignedUrl</Key>